# Sudden strange R error on EC2 instance for cronjobs

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I have a bunch of R scripts running via cronjobs like so:

```
0 */01 * * * R CMD BATCH /home/ubuntu/Documents/Scripts/TwitterScrapes/scrapeTwitterATTSwitch.R /home/ubuntu/Documents/Scripts/TwitterScrapes/logs/ATTReport-$(date -u +\%Y\%m\%dt\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

This has worked fine for a few months on an EC2 instance, when suddenly I'm getting these errors for all scripts. They don't even execute at all.

```
Error: ReadItem: unknown type 111, perhaps written by later version of R
Execution halted
```

I've tried `update.packages` and rebooting the instance, but nothing has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--no-restore` to each R CMD BATCH call in crontab fixed the problem.